# Linq OrderBy int property does not work

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an IEnumerable of custom objects - allBanners, one of the property is called **Order** and is of type **int**. 
My usage is like below:

```
var bannersVisibleToEveryone = allBanners
                                .Where(b => b.UserSegments.Contains("Everyone"))
                                .OrderBy(b => b.Order)
                                .Take(moreBanners)
                                .ToList();
```

When I inspect the bannersVisibleToEveryone after the above line - the list is not sorted at all - it is randomly sorted as the allBanners is. 
Why is that?

[image: Screenshot of the debug below]

**EDIT:** on the screenshot it looks like it is ordered descending (which is wrong too, because I am using orderBy, not orderByDescending), but the fourth element's Order is 350, so it is not ordered descending, sorry for the misleading screenshot.

**EDIT 2:** Complete method definition:

```
public static List<T> GetBannersForCurrentUser<T>(IEnumerable<T> allBanners,
                                                IEnumerable<string> userSegments,
                                                int maxNumberOfBanners)
where T : ICitilinkItem
{
var filteredBanners = allBanners
                                .Where(b => userSegments.Any(us => b.UserSegments.Contains(us)))
                                .OrderBy(b => b.Order)
                                .Take(maxNumberOfBanners)
                                .ToList();

int moreBanners = maxNumberOfBanners - filteredBanners.Count;
if (moreBanners > 0 && !userSegments.Contains("Everyone"))
{
    //add the banners from Everyone
    var bannersVisibleToEveryone = allBanners
                                        .Where(b => b.UserSegments.Contains("Everyone"))
                                        .OrderBy(b => b.Order)
                                        .Take(moreBanners)
                                        .OrderBy(b => b.Order)
                                        .ToList();

    filteredBanners.AddRange(bannersVisibleToEveryone);
}
return filteredBanners;
}
```

And the getter of the Order property:

```
public interface ICitilinkItem
{
string Title { get; set; }

string UserSegments { get; set; }

int Order { get; set; }
}

public class CitilinkModelBase : ICitilinkItem
{
public string Title { get; set; }

public string UserSegments { get; set; }

public int Order { get; set; }

public CitilinkModelBase()
{

}
}
```

Comment: I don't see where's the "random" order. It goes from 500 to 100!

Comment: It's sorting in descending order...

Comment: @User2012384 Well, but this isn't random, is it

Comment: what is morebanners in Take?

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code?

Comment: Try without the take and see what results you get.

Comment: It's useless, but how this sample in DotNetFiddle works and yours has the issue? https://dotnetfiddle.net/9xYsuk

Comment: Updated my question with the info about the descending order - it is not sorted by descending order, even if it were - that would have been wrong because I am using OrderBy, not OrderByDescending.

Comment: Still, without code, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: And what does the getter of `Order` look like? What is the type of `allBanners`?

Comment: have you tried to remove both take and tolist , to see if it gets orderd ?

Comment: Updated code above. Yes, I tried with removing the Take and ToList - still the same.

Answer (score 4):

Mystery solved - I had a class HomePageBanner which was inheriting the CitilinkModelBase base class AND also defines an **Order** property which was hiding the underlying one. Thanks @odyss-jii for pointing me in the right direction.